# Knowledge not showing up in SOQL query even after (SeeAllData=true) (Lightning)

Tags: apex, permissions, sharing, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I have deliberately mentioned `SeeAllData=true` to test some business functionality just in my org.
But in System mode the same query returns data, but in Community User context the same query does not return any data.

There are no `Data Catergories`, and also the sharing setting for `Knowledge` has been made to `Public Read Only` for external users. I have also assigned Record Types and Object Read permission via a custom permission.
I have even tried changing from `with sharing` to `without sharing`.

Where and what else can I check?

```
// This is community user
List<User> user = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username = 'pe-site-staff-1502@iqviavtpescratch.org'];
List<Knowledge__kav> knowledgeKav2 = [SELECT Id, UrlName, Title FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Audience__c = 'Site Staff'];
System.debug(knowledgeKav2); // data comes here because of system mode
System.runAs(user[0]){
    List<Knowledge__kav> knowledgeKav = [SELECT Id, UrlName, Title FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Audience__c = 'Site Staff']; // but data does not comes because of user context.
    System.debug(i);
}
```

Comment: Just not checked, this field needs to be checked from UI for a KA to be avaiable in Customer Portal `IsVisibleInCsp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lightning knowledge with no categories available and with Knowledge sharing enabled. Just make sure these two things are enabled.

1. In OWD settings, external read access is provided
2. On each knowledge Article there is a field `IsVisibleInCsp` which needs to be checked. Only then the knowledge article is available in query or to Customer community users.